# Find if a procedure is running in another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form X with the following procedure:

```
Public Sub PrintUT_Click()

If Forms!frmDisclosure.Command280.Visible = True Then
    Forms!frmDisclosure.GoToLastRecord
End If

RemoveSchma
DoCmd.TransferText acExportMerge, "", "qryUndertaking", conAddrPth &   "\DataSource.txt", True, "", 1252
OpenWordDoc

ExecuteFile "E:\Peter\Desktop\Update Service.pdf", printfile

End Sub
```

It is called from another form (form Y) from one of two command buttons. If called fom one button I want 'ExecuteFile "E:\Peter\Desktop\Update Service.pdf", printfile' to run. If called from the other button, I don't want 'Exceute...' to run. What 'If... Then' prodecure can I set up in form X to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a boolean switch as a parameter, moving the routine out of a button event and into it's own sub.

```
Private Sub Button1()
RoutineNameHere
End Sub

Private Sub Button2()
RoutineNameHere False
End Sub

Public Sub RoutineNameHere(Optional blnExecute as Boolean=True)
If Forms!frmDisclosure.Command280.Visible = True Then
    Forms!frmDisclosure.GoToLastRecord
End If

RemoveSchma
DoCmd.TransferText acExportMerge, "", "qryUndertaking", conAddrPth &   "\DataSource.txt", True, "", 1252
OpenWordDoc

If blnExecute Then
    ExecuteFile "E:\Peter\Desktop\Update Service.pdf", printfile
End If
End Sub
```